# Is it true that there's no advantage in filing patents to each major patent office rather than filing it through the PCT system?

Tags: patents, epo

Is it true that there's no advantage in filing patents to each major patent office rather than filing it through the PCT system? PCT applications is used as a figure for innovation, but it seems that there are companies that forgo using the PCT system to apply for patents in Europe, Japan and the U.S. Are there advantages in doing so, or no advantage in filing patents in each patent office individually?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's better asked at https://patents.stackexchange.com

Comment: @BlueDogRanch If the question is Law related, it is appropriate here. There is a Meta discussing this.

Comment: Patents SE is dead. To the extent that a question is about the law or legal process, it is on-topic here, and to the extent it will actually be answered, should stay open here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be a cost saving if the applicant knows early in the process where they need to file and it is a small number of places. One can also get earlier allowances by filing directly. The PCT process lets you delay deciding where to actually file that is a plus unless you know where you what to go. There are also regional filings like the EPO that allow one filing which can end up with multiple patents in one or more of the EPO countries.